# Java EE Firing an Event creates a new Instance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, observer-pattern, managed-bean, session-scope

I have two ManagedBeans.

Concerning my problem, they do the following:

First:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Provider {

    private Event<ProvideEvent> event;

    private static boolean handling = false;
    public provide(@Observes ConsumeEvent consume){
      if(!handling){
        //provide some stuff
        event.fire(new ProvideEvent(ProvidedStuff stuff);
      }
    }
}
```

Second:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Consumer {

    private Event<ConsumeEvent> event;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
      event.fire(new ConsumeEvent());  
    }

    private static boolean handling = false;
    public consume(@Observes ProvideEvent providedStuff){
      if(!handling){
        //use the provided stuff
      }
    }
}
```

This happens, when the website is called:
1. Consumer is instantiated.
2. Consumer fires the event.
3. Provider is instantiated.
4. provide() is called.
5. A NEW CONSUMER IS INSTANTIATED
6. consume() is called.

As you can see, I had to use a boolean "handling" to keep the application from looping infinitly.

Why is the container not using the instantiated SessionScoped ManagedBean? I thought SessionScoped ManagedBeans are like Singleton for the Session?
I guess I could work around this by:
 A: Using static variables for the changed properties.
 B: Implementing the Observer-Pattern manually.

But there has to be an easier way here!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem could be that you fire the event in the `@PostConstruct` method of your `Customer`.

From the javadocs:

> This method MUST be invoked before the class is put into service.

As far as I understand, that results in a race condition. The `Provider` is probably firing the second event earlier than your `Customer` instance finishes executing `initialize()` and  the container puts it into service. Hence, it won't receive the event. I'm too inexperienced with Java EE to give good advice how to prevent that race condition though. I would probably work around it with an ugly `SynchronousQueue` as a meeting point.

Additional info: the default with `@Observes` is to create a new instance of the event receiver if none exists (is in service). That's why another customer is created. Use `@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS)` to only notify existing instances that are in service.

> I thought SessionScoped ManagedBeans are like Singleton for the Session?

No, it just defines the lifetime of the object(s). It doesn't really enforce session-singleton behavior. The container would probably prefer the existing instance though, if it was in service at the time the second event is fired.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved it now by implementing the Observer-Pattern by myself. But I will try if your approach works and get back to you.

Comment: I finally found time to reproduce the problem ;) You were right, it does create problems firing events from the @PostConstruct method. Thanks again for your help.